# Async / Callstack confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callstack

Alrighty, I'm pretty sure I know what the issue is, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve it.

The way the below code works is the front-end sends two words back to the server, some sanitization happens and breaks the string into an array. That array is then iterated over, an async request is made for each word to the Wordnik API for synonyms. The resulting data structure sent back to the client is an object with `{word1: [...synonyms], word2: [...synonyms]}`.

With two words, this works exactly how I want 4 out of 5 times. That fifth time, the synonyms for the second word get applied to the first word and the second word has no data. Obviously, send it more words and the data confusion occurs more often.

So, I'm pretty sure this is a call stack issue, but I can't figure out how to resolve it. I keep thinking if I wrap the wordnikClient in setTimeout(..., 0); it's a step in the right direction, but feel like I'm misapplying the pattern. Any words of wisdom out there?

EDIT: https://github.com/ColinTheRobot/tweetsmithy-node/blob/master/server.js This was the prior version it has the same async issue. I had initially designed it with a Promise, but realized over the last couple days, that it wasn't really doing anything/I had also probably misapplied it so took it out for now.

```
app.get('/get-synonyms', (req, res) => {
    var tweetWords = sanitizeTweet(req.query.data);
    getDefs(tweetWords, res);
});

var getDefs = function(tweetWords, res) {
    var i = 0;
    var serialized = {};

    tweetWords.forEach((word) => {
        wordnikClient(word, (body) => {
            var wordToFind = tweetWords[i];
            var shortenedWords = [];
            i++;

            if (body[0]) {
                shortenedWords = _.filter(body, (syn) => {
                    return syn.length < wordToFind.length;
                });
                serialized[wordToFind] = shortenedWords;
            }

            if (tweetWords.length == i) {
                res.send(serialized);
            }
        });
    });
}

var sanitizeTweet = function(tweet) {
    var downcasedString = tweet.toLowerCase();
    var punctuationless = downcasedString.replace(/[.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
    return finalString.split(' ');
}

var wordnikClient = function(word, callback) {
    var url = `http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/${word}/relatedWords?useCanonical=false&relationshipTypes=synonym&limitPerRelationshipType=10&api_key=${process.env.WORDNIK_API_KEY}`
    console.log('calling client');
    request(url, (err, response, body) => {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200 && response.body != '[]') {
            callback(JSON.parse(body)[0].words);
        } else if (!err && response.statusCode == 200 && response.body == '[]') {
            callback([false]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If the second request comes first, it'll make `var wordToFind = tweetWords[i];` be the first word, which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what is happening is that your second async call is completing first and because fo

```
if (tweetWords.length == i) {
            res.send(serialized);
        }
    });
```

is returning to the client. One alternative is to use https://github.com/caolan/async to cooridnate your async calls, but I would suggest you convert `wordnikClient` to promises and then use `Promise.all` to control `res.send`

```
var wordnikClient = function(word) {
    var url = `http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/${word}/relatedWords?useCanonical=false&relationshipTypes=synonym&limitPerRelationshipType=10&api_key=${process.env.WORDNIK_API_KEY}`
    console.log('calling client');
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, (err, response, body) => {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200 && response.body != '[]') {
            resolve(JSON.parse(body)[0].words);
        } else if (!err && response.statusCode == 200 && response.body == '[]') {
            reject([false]);
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
Promise.all(tweetWords.map((word) => wordnikClient(word)))
.then(serialized => res.send(serialized))
.catch(err  => res.status(500).send(err))
```

I've probably lost a little functionality along the way but you can re-add that

Comment: Thank you @simon, that was exactly what I needed to do. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. In theory, I understood/understand that the call stack wasn't running the methods in the order i wanted and could see it by console logging.

Answer (score 1):

What the asynchronous callbacks do inside `getDefs` is not clear. The `i` variable counts the order of the replies, so I don't see why to use that to index `tweetWords`. I suggest you to use just `word` instead. A somewhat clearer solution could be made using Promises:

```
function getDefs(tweetWords, res) {
    var serialized = {};

    Promise.all(tweetWords.map(word => {
      return wordnikClientAsync(word).then(body => {
        if (body[0]) {
          serialized[word] = _.filter(body, syn => syn.length < word.length);
        }
      });
    })).then(() => {
      res.send(serialized);
    }, () => {
      res.send("Error");
    });

    function wordnikClientAsync(word) {
        return new Promise(resolve => wordnikClient(word, resolve));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `tweetWords[i];` for `word` because the variable is outside the callback and iteration may don't run currently.

Comment: Word! haha. Yeah... duh. I still need to resolve the request order, but this solves my data getting confused. So foolish. Thanks